# How to upgrade VSIX to make it compatible with VS 15 Preview 5?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, visual-studio-sdk, vsixmanifest

When I try to install my VSIX to [VS 15 Preview 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/10/05/announcing-visual-studio-15-preview-5) I get the warning

> "This extension is not compatible with Visual Studio 15 and will not be supported in RC":

[image: VSIX installation warning]

[Microsoft blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/10/05/announcing-visual-studio-15-preview-5) does not provide any notes about this issue.

This should be related to a new VSIX manifest format, which is JSON instead of XML, but I can not find any info regarding upgrade process of the manifest.

How to upgrade my manifest to resolve this issue?

Comment: It is covered pretty well in the Oct 5th release notes.  It isn't done yet.  Inevitable liability with an early preview of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download upgrade documentation to VSIXv3 from [this link](https://aka.ms/vs15preview5extensionsdk).

Mostly you should use VS "15" and add `<GenerateVsixV3>true</GenerateVsixV3>` to your project file. That will add `manifest.json` to your new vsix.

Answer (score 0):

From the release notes linked in the blog post:

Further information and tooling for specifying dependencies in the new extension format will be available in the next release, allowing extension developers to update their extensions prior to the final release of Visual Studio "15".

https://www.visualstudio.com/news/releasenotes/vs15-relnotes#KIother